# error: cannot convert ‘dirent*’ to ‘search_directories(std::string, std::list<start_tournament_info_t*>&, bool)::direct*’

Tags: c++, gcc, dirent.h

I am trying to compile this project [Realtimebattle reloaded (github)](https://github.com/mdtrooper/RealTimeBattle_reloaded/tree/master/RealtimeBattle/original_gtk).

But the gcc throws weird error:

```
RealTimeBattle_reloaded/RealtimeBattle/original_gtk/src/Various.cc:473:30: error: cannot convert ‘dirent*’ to ‘search_directories(std::string, std::list<start_tournament_info_t*>&, bool)::direct*’ in assignment
       while( NULL != ( entry = readdir( dir ) ) )
```

And the source code is:

```
void
search_directories( string directory,
                    list<start_tournament_info_t*>& tour_list,
                    const bool check_robots )
{
  bool err_in_file = false;
  DIR* dir;
  if( NULL != ( dir = opendir(directory.c_str()) ) )
    {
      struct dirent* entry;
      while( NULL != ( entry = readdir( dir ) ) )
        {
          string full_file_name = directory + entry->d_name;
          bool res = false;
          if(check_robots)
            res = check_if_filename_is_robot(full_file_name, &err_in_file);
          else
            res = check_if_filename_is_arena(full_file_name, &err_in_file);
          if(res)
            {
              start_tournament_info_t* info;
              info = new start_tournament_info_t(0, false, full_file_name, "");
              tour_list.push_back( info );
            }
        }
      closedir(dir);
    }
}
```

I am very confused with the log.

Comment: Are you sure you the code and error you posted match what you're seeing locally? Twice you wrote that the error references `direct` rather than `dirent`, but the former type isn't used by your posted code. Does that typo exist in the original code? If not, please generate and post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The original version didn't use CMake: https://github.com/ezag/realtimebattle

This is probably an incomplete port over to the CMake build system.

What's happening here is the code depends on macros being defined during compile-time.

Placing: '#define HAVE_DIRENT_H' at the top of Various.cc will probably make that part of the code compile... but there are probably more issues than just that one case.